# Executing tar command with Python subprocess does not exclude certain files when given --exclude option

Tags: python, tar

I am executing below tar command using python subprocess module

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["/bin/tar", "-czf", "file.tar.gz", "./dir", "--exclude", "\"*cpp*\""]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

but the exclusion of cpp files are not happening.

When I run the same command in the shell prompt it is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the `--exclude` and `*cpp*` potentially should be in the same string

Comment: Leave out the literal quotes.

Comment: There is a `=` missing () `"--exclude=*cpp*"`

Comment: @uphill, it's legal to pass the pattern as a separate argument from the `--exclude`; in that case, no `=` is expected. So the usage you describe is valid, but not required.

Comment: In any case, `shlex.split()` should be used to convert a command string into a list. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave out the literal quotes. That is:

```
cmd = ["/bin/tar", "-czf", "file.tar.gz", "--exclude", "*cpp*", "./dir"]
```

Otherwise, you're only excluding files whose names start and end with `"`.

---

To explain why this is: When you write `--exclude "*cpp*"` in shell, those quotes are *syntactic*, not literal. They tell the shell not to replace `*cpp*` with a list of files; they *aren't* passed to `tar` themselves.

Comment: and both these format works for me **cmd = ["/bin/tar", "-cvzf", "file.tar.gz", "./dir", "--exclude={0}".format('*cpp')]**
**cmd = ["/bin/tar", "-cvzf", "file.tar.gz", "./dir", "--exclude", "{0}".format('*cpp*')]**

Comment: @IbrahimQuraish, ...though I'm not really sure what the point to that is. `"{0}".format("*cpp") == "*cpp"` is always true. BTW, use backticks if you want to provide literal code in comments, without characters like `*` being treated as formatting rather than printed.